# getting result metadata from coldfusion newQuery() in cfscript

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery

Documentation on CFscript is a bit sparse in the docs, and searching for a cfscript specific answer gets lost in CF tag answers. So here's my question:

How do I get the result metadata from a query that was performed using script? Using tags I can add `result="myNamedResultVar"` to my cfquery. I can then refer to the query `name` for data, or `myNamedResultVar` for some metadata. However, now I'm trying to write everything in script, so my component is script based, top-to-bottom.  What I'm ultimately after is the last inserted Id from a MySQL insert. That ID exists in the `result` metadata.

```
myNamedResultVar.getPrefix().generatedkey
```

Here's my query code:

```
public any function insertUser( required string name, required string email, required string pass ) {
    // insert user
    var sql     = '';
    var tmp     = '';
    var q       = new query();

        q.setDatasource( application.dsn );

        q.addParam(
                    name='name'
                    ,value='#trim( arguments.name )#'
                    ,cfsqltype='CF_SQL_VARCHAR'
                );
        q.addParam(
                    name='email'
                    ,value='#trim( arguments.email )#'
                    ,cfsqltype='CF_SQL_VARCHAR'
                );
        q.addParam(
                    name='pass'
                    ,value='#hashMyString( arguments.pass )#'
                    ,cfsqltype='CF_SQL_VARCHAR'
                );


        sql = 'INSERT INTO
                    users
                    (
                        name
                        ,email
                        ,pass
                        ,joined
                        ,lastaccess
                    )
                VALUES
                    (
                        :name
                        ,:email
                        ,:pass
                        ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                        ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                    );
            ';

        tmp = q.execute( sql=sql );

        q.clearParams();

}
```

How do I specify the result data? I've tried something like this:
    ...
    tmp = q.execute( sql=sql );

```
var r = tmp.getResult();
    r = r.getPrefix().generatedkey;

q.clearParams();

return r;
```

However, on an insert the `getResult()` returns a NULL as best I can tell. So the `r.getPrefix().generatedkey` does NOT work after an insert. I get `r` is undefined

Comment: What is the problem? `r.getPrefix().generatedkey` will get the inserted record ID.

Comment: on a select - I presume you're correct...
however on an insert the getResult() returns a NULL as best I can tell.
so the r.getPrefix().generatedkey does NOT work after an insert.
I get r is undefined

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the `result` property of the query first and then from that you are trying to get the `prefix` property in result. But this is not the case. You can directly get the `prefix` property and then the generated key like this:

```
tmp.getPrefix().generatedkey;
```

For reference you can check this blog entry: [Getting the Generated Key From A Query in ColdFusion (Including Script Based Queries)](http://blog.bittersweetryan.com/2011/01/getting-generated-key-from-query-in.html)

Comment: Good catch.  IMO, it was a poor choice for method names on the part of Adobe.  Given that the tag version uses `result` to return the `generatedkey`, naturally most folks try `getResult()`. However, the docs mention the cryptically named `getPrefix()` method is the one you want here: *Prefix: Equivalent to the result attribute for the cfquery tag*.

Answer (score 1):

after some futzing... THIS seems to work

```
... tmp = q.execute( sql=sql );

        var  r = tmp.getPrefix( q ).generatedkey;

        q.clearParams();

    return r;
```