# How do I get the generated key for an MSSQL "insert" query in Coldfusion 2021 script?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

### Problem

I want to get the id of the inserted row from a SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO NameList (Name) VALUES('John')
```

I need to do this in Coldfusion 2021 script, like in the following:

```
var sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO NameList (Name) VALUES(?)";
var params = [{ value: "John", cfsqltype: "cf_sql_varchar" }];

try {
    var executedQuery = queryExecute(sqlQuery, params, {/* ...other options... */});
    
    //This is where it fails, because getResult() returns NULL.
    var insertedId = executedQuery.getResult().GENERATEDKEY;
}
catch (any ex) {
    //...report the error, read ex.message
}
```

But this does not work because **getResult()** returns NULL.

### Research

I've read that the proper way to get the data is not through **getResult()**, but with **getPrefix()** from this StackOverflow answer: [getting result metadata from coldfusion newQuery() in cfscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278590/getting-result-metadata-from-coldfusion-newquery-in-cfscript)

But this does not work, **getPrefix()** also returns NULL. I cannot find documentation on this function on CFDocs.org or Adobe's documentation (though Adobe's documentation is tough for me to navigate).

The **getPrefix()** function does not work on cffiddle.org either, so I can't test it otherwise.

### Temporary solution

I *have* been able to get the id of the inserted row using a style I am trying to avoid: passing in a named **result** variable through queryExecute's *option* parameter.

```
//...clipped...
try {
    //The options.result parameter is set to 'queryResult'.
    var executedQuery = queryExecute(sqlQuery, params, { result = "queryResult" });
    
    //This works, though I'm not sure where 'queryResult' exists in scope.
    var insertedId = queryResult.GENERATEDKEY;
}
//...clipped...
```

I don't know what scope *queryResult* is in (is it global?), but this works. I would prefer passing in a local variable, but passing in `{ result = "someLocalVar" }` led to bugs.

Is there a way to pass in a local variable? I would find this acceptable.

### Conclusion

I want to get the id of the inserted row using Coldfusion 2021 script. I would prefer not using the *options.result* parameter of queryExecute(), but instead using **getResult()** or a similar mechanism.

If that's not possible, then I would prefer being able to pass in a local variable to the *options.result* parameter of queryExecute().

If that's not possible, then I'd like to know at least what scope the variable referenced by *options.result* is.

Comment: Seems, `getResult()` belongs to the *ancient* *sql.cfc* https://blog.mattclemente.com/2016/03/04/using-queryexecute-on-coldfusion-11.html

Comment: @BernhardDöbler That blog link answered multiple questions: the scope of the variable referenced by *options.result* is the variable scope by default. You can specify a local variable as *var someLocalVar = ''* beforehand, and then you can use that in *options.result*. And *queryExecute()* returns undefined when executing an INSERT. Thank you for the reference!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var executedQuery = queryExecute(sqlQuery, params, { result = "queryResult" });
```

Take a look at the parameters, you are specifying the result to be queryResult.  Therefor that has the generated key.

The docs indicate that you do not need to specify the result ( https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/queryexecute.html ) and that re result/return of queryExecute result the resul but this seams to not work as per docs in ACF2021.

I would suggest below.

```
try {
  var executedQuery = ''; 
  queryExecute(sqlQuery, params, { result = "executedQuery" });
  var insertedId = executedQuery.GENERATEDKEY;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I can see how to declare a local variable, and then use that in the options parameter. That solution works for me!

Answer (score 0):

In CF 2016 this works:

```
var result = insert.execute().getPrefix();

var insertedId = result.generatedKey;
```

For newer version this should work:

```
var result = insert.execute().getResult();

var insertedId = result.generatedKey;
```